# Store and Reference Array Values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, arrays

I want to make a table that holds an array of data, say user IDs, so it will hold a given number of string values. With this table's array, I want to be able to reference the array values from a single attribute of a second table.

Will I be able to do this, or is there another way that I will have to do this?
Thank you kindly for any help.

Comment: Can you add some sample data to your question?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the question.